# How to add an A Record so Subdomain-less request reach my server

Tags: dns, subdomain

I have a domain `mydomain.com`, and i already set an A record for `*.mydomain.com`, all request for any subdomain are reaching my server except http://mydomain.com. How can I setup my records so that http://mydoamin.com requests will reach my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try leaving the name of the record blank. Only do type A and value.

Comment: Many domain hosts don't allow you to leave this field blank. They usually require you to enter some special character, like "@" to mean "anything including blank".